# How to Draw This RCL Circuit with Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, qcircuit

I am a total newbie using circuitikz.

Please how do I draw the attached RCL Circuit diagram?
[image: RCL Circuit]

I'll be glad to be helped

Comment: What you try so far? If you at listed package documentation you should see similar example in it. Also here on size ar number of answers with similar schemas. Make some research please, so far your question is just ask that your job do some instead of you.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is some very simple circuit, and if you want to get anywhere with circuitikz I recommend being able to draw it yourself after reading the tutorials and some bit of documentations.

That being said, since I could not find a simple RLC circuit to mark this question as a duplicate and because you have some non-standard representation of components, here is how I would to it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[straightvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [short] ++(0,1) node [right] {$-$}
    to [open, v^>=$E(t)$, o-o] ++(0,1) node [right] {$+$}
    to [short] ++(0,1)
    to [R=$R$, i>^=$I$, resistors/zigs=6] ++(4,0)
    to [curved capacitor, l_=$C$, capacitors/thickness=8] ++(0,-3)
    to [cute inductor, l_=$L$, mirror] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image: RLC circuit]

Comment: Nice. But for the "mirrored" inductor, you can do `... to[cute inductor, l_=$L$, mirror] (0,0)`, no need to create another path. And you can try also `to[R=$R$, resistors/zigs=9`... to have a very busy resistor ;-). And `capacitors/thickness=6` also!

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, I’ve updated the code with your suggestions. ;)

Comment: Thank you all. I'm wondering of the code to shift the position of the arrow and E(t) westwards as in the original diagram? @Rmano

Comment: @ChikaOdiliobi that *should* be possible with `open voltage position=legacy` (see page 175 of the manual), but you just found a bug (try it).  You can workaround it with (in the voltage line) `to [open, v^>=~, o-o, open voltage position=legacy, l=$E(t)$, label distance=6pt] ++(0,1) node [right] {$+$}`.

Comment: Opened an issue here https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/584 .