# How can I do a circuit on LaTex?

Tags: circuits

I need to do a drawing of this circuit on my TeX, can anyone help me with the code to make it?[image]

Comment: There are many examples of circuits on this site. Have you done a proper search and looked at some answers? For example, just look at the [tag:circuits] tag (there are also others).

Comment: also this tag https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuitikz

Comment: I recommend reading the basics of `circuitikz` if you want to get anywhere with drawing circuits. ;) That being said, I recently posted [an example of a similar circuit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617610/56823).

Comment: Thanks to you all that comment, I appreciate the help. I'll be reading the basics and searching on the tags to be able to make the circuit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can be answered by reading the documentation for `circuitikz`.

Comment: Or the documentation of  `pst-circ`.

Comment: I made the circuit. Thanks to you all.

Comment: Awesome, congrats on drawing your first circuit!

Answer (score 1):

It's rather easy with `pstricks`, more specifically with the dedicated package – `pst-circ`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\sansmath
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3,3)
\psset{unit = 1.5cm, linejoin=1}
\pnodes(0,0){A}(0,4){B}(4,4){C}(4,0){D}
\vac[labeloffset=32pt](A)(B){CA}
\resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=20pt](B)(C){R1}
\coil(C)(D){L1}
\capacitor(D)(A){C1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]